# Create function but only for use in VBA environment (not in workbook formulas)

Tags: vba, function, excel

This is new to me - I've created a function that I use for updating a SQL Server table via VBA. It takes in a range of cells and it returns a `Long` of how many records were affected.

So, I would like this function to be available throughout my workbooks for use within VBA, but don't want it to show up as an available formula in Excel (outside of the VBA environment).

I'm sure I've done this before, but can't remember how to hide my Function from Excel so it's only for use in VBA.

How can I do this?

Comment: Declare it as `Private`?

Comment: @DavidZemens, thanks, but I do want to use it across workbooks (I want to keep it in my personal.xls), I just don't want it to be used in Excel directly.

Comment: Then make it a `Sub` instead of a `Function`.

Comment: But I want to return the number of rows affected... I guess I could pass an int `ByRef` to get that value, but I'm hoping there's a nicer way....

Comment: If you do `Call mySubroutine(i)` then the variable is passed `ByRef`. if you simply do `mySubroutine(i)` then the variable is passed `ByVal`.  Alternatively, you can explicitly require the variables `ByRef` in the receiving procedure.

Comment: :) - Duly noted, @DavidZemens - I always mention it explicitly for my own sake, but I know you're right :). I'm still hoping to keep it a function if I could since it truly is something that returns a value....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move it into its own module (.bas), and stick `Option Private Module` at the top. Done; Excel won't see it anymore, but VBA will (and COM add-ins can see it too, so I figure a referencing VBA project could see it as well).

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a sub and pass the parameters `ByRef`.  With an integer/long variable, you can accomplish this a few different ways:

See examples:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim i as Long

    i = 1

    bar (i)    'Variable is passed ByVal because parens FORCE an evaluation, you aren't passing "i", you're passing the expression "(i)".  

    Debug.Print i

    bar i      'Variable is passed ByRef even without explicitly doing so

    Debug.Print i

    anotherFunction i     'Variable is passed ByRef, same as above
    Debug.Print "i: " & CStr(i)

    anotherFunction (i)   'Variable is passed ByVal because parens FORCE an evaluation

    Call anotherFunction(i)  'Variable is passed byRef
End Sub

Sub bar(val As Long)
Dim j
For j = 1 To 10
    val = val + 1
    Debug.Print "j: " & CStr(val)
Next
End Sub

Sub anotherFunction(ByRef val as Long)
Dim j
For j = 1 To 10
    val = val + 1
    Debug.Print "j: " & CStr(val)
Next
End Sub
```